# BERT tokenize URLs

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I want to classify a bunch of tweets and therefore I'm using the huggingface implementation of BERT. However I noticed that the deafult BertTokenizer does not use special tokens for urls.

```py
>>> from transformers import BertTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
>>> tokenizer.tokenize("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
['https', ':', '/', '/', 'stack', '##over', '##flow', '.', 'com', '/', 'questions', '/', 'ask']
```

This seems quite inefficent to me. What would be the best way, to encode URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends. If the URL contains information that is relevant for the classification, then the best thing you can do is keeping it as it is. There certainly were some URLs in the pre-training data and BERT learned how to handle them properly.

If you are sure, the URLs are irrelevant for the classificaion, you can replace them by a special token, which is a very common thing to do in NLP in general. But in that case, you need to fine-tune BERT, so it knows what the special token mean. If you do not fine-tune BERT and only train a classifier on top of it, then again, the best thing you can do is keeping the URLs as they are.

Comment: I would say that the URLs are not relevant in my case. Do you think finetuning is sufficent to introduce a completly new token?

Comment: In general, yes, but it of course depends on how much data you have.

Comment: In addition to the recommendation to keep the URLs as-is, you might want to consider removing the URL part trailing the domain, i.e. `http://google.com/something` => `http://google.com`.